# User cannot see certain discord bot commands

Tags: discord, discord.js, command, bots, chatbot

We have a specific user that cannot see certain slash commands but yet every other members can see them. We have tried everything we can think of to fix the issue. Different device, incognito mode, uninstall and reinstall, clear cache and cookies, etc.

No matter what we try, this one user cannot see the slash commands of 3 of our bots but yet they have an alt account that can see the commands and every other user can see them. We went through every role they have in the community and those roles are not causing the issue for them.

Our bot dev is adamant it isn't a bot issue and discord support is saying it isn't their account. They don't get any errors if they try the commands either, they just straight up can't see them.

Example /ping would ping the bot but they can't see that command yet everyone else can see it and it works fine. It used to work on their phone but now it doesn't. This has been going on for several days.

Comment: Have you checked your channel permissions? Does the user have `Use Application Commands` permission?

Comment: Yeah we have gone through every role that they have and every channel. They have been given access to "Use Application Commands" and yet 3 of the 6 bots do not recognize them when they try to use the / command.

Comment: Sounds like those 3 commands got some `defaultMemberPermissions` set on them. If a command has a `defaultMemberPermission` on it and the member does not have this permission, the command will not be shown to the member.